# Does "moving a meeting forward" mean the time will be earlier or later?

Tags: time

Suppose I say "We're moving the 12 PM meeting forward 2 hours", does that mean the meeting is at 10 AM or 2 PM?

Comment: updoot this comment if you think its 10 AM

Comment: updoot this comment if you think its 2 PM

Comment: In this context, forward means it happens sooner. Upvote this comment if you know I'm right.

Comment: I upvoted @Robusto’s comment.  Upvote this if you think I did the right thing.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think asking for people to vote for comments is not in the spirit of the Stack Exchange question and answer format.

Comment: See also: https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2018/apr/13/time-move-meeting-forward-oliver-burkeman ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you move a meeting forward, you are scheduling it earlier. See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bring-forward).

There is, however, a lot of confusion about terms like *up*, *back*, *forward*, and *out* when they are used in this context. As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/scheduling-woes-and-the-ambiguous-adverbs-that-cause-them) suggests, the best way to handle them is probably not to use them at all, and substitute less ambiguous words like *earlier* and *later* in their place.

Comment: The collins link refers to "bring forward" which is more generally accepted to mean earlier in time than "move forward" is

Answer (score 0):

Technically "you bring forward" or "you move back". It's not good English to say move forward in this context. You can move forward in a line up or a queue but not when talking about time....